# IndexedDB storage quota on Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, indexeddb, quota

Now that finally Blobs are supported, I am writing a video caching layer to recall N recently downloaded videos.

Is there a way to query IndexedDB for the maximum allowed storage? 
Is there a way to request a quota increase?

I am asking because none of the info I found searching seems to apply anymore. I have so far stored hundreds of megabytes of videos although some articles talk of a 5 (or sometimes 20) mb limit. I hope I am not building against a bug.

100+ mb stored so far with no issues using chrome 38.0.2125

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Chrome limit on IndexedDB (or any storage) so far as OS can provide. Also note, IndexedDB storage are temporary storage and can be purged without notifying to the app. When [Quota Management API](http://www.w3.org/TR/quota-api/), you will have assurance of persistent storage.